# Can you upgrade a Qantas flight with Enrich points?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, qantas, malaysia-airlines

**Is it possible to upgrade a Qantas flight with Enrich (Malaysia Airlines) points?**

Do Qantas allow flyers to use frequent flyer points from other one world airlines? I know that business lounge access is across all one-world members, but it does not specify on their website from what I can tell, whether I can upgrade my Qantas flight with Enrich points.

Enrich is a [one-world](/questions/tagged/one-world) group, just like Qantas — so I presume that it is possible, but their website does not go into detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to upgrade a Qantas flight with Malaysia points.

Unlike [Star Alliance](https://www.qantas.com/fflyer/dyn/flying/using-points-qantas-jetstar), for example, [oneworld does not](https://www.oneworld.com/ffp/oneworld-benefits) have a generalized scheme for point-based upgrades on partner flights. That is, you can use points in one oneworld program to redeem a premium ticket on another oneworld carrier, but you cannot use them to upgrade a paid ticket on a partner to a more premium cabin. Individual member airlines do have arrangements with other members— for example, you can use American AAdvantage miles to upgrade [on British Airways and Iberia](https://www.aa.com/i18n/aadvantage-program/miles/redeem/award-travel/upgrade-with-miles-on-partner-airlines.jsp)— but you must check with the carrier.

Qantas makes upgrades very difficult in general, and does not allow upgrades using points from any partner airlines. There is no mention of partners on their [Using Points](https://www.qantas.com/fflyer/dyn/flying/using-points-qantas-jetstar) guide. "Classic Upgrade" rewards are only listed as available using Qantas/Jetstar upgrade instruments.

Even for a [Bid Now Upgrade](https://www.qantas.com/travel/airlines/upgrade/global/en), you can only use Qantas points or cash:

> You will need to bid using a combination of Qantas Points and money if you are a Qantas Frequent Flyer*, or money only if you are not a Qantas Frequent Flyer. A minimum Points and money amount apply.